# Copy Elision instead of copy constructor inside a container?

Tags: c++, containers

I'm trying to implement my own `vector` container, and while implementing the `push_back()` method, I thought of using Copy Elision (copy memory) of the already constructed objects instead of using the copy constructor on each one of them. So the code seems like:

```
void push_back(const value_type& val)
{
    pointer     tmp;
    size_type   newCapacity;

    if (_capacity == _size)
    {
        newCapacity = _getNewCapacity(_capacity * 2);
        tmp = _allocator.allocate(newCapacity);
        try
        {
            _allocator.construct(tmp + _size, val);
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            _allocator.deallocate(tmp, newCapacity);
        }
        _normalSwap(_data, tmp);
        _copyElision(tmp, 0, 0, _size);
        _allocator.deallocate(tmp, _capacity);
        _capacity = newCapacity;
    }
    else
        _allocator.construct(_data + _size, val);
    ++_size;
}
```

Where `copyElision()` is coded as:

```
void _copyElision(pointer src, size_type dstStart, size_type srcStart, size_type srcEnd)
{
    if (srcEnd > srcStart)
        ::memmove(_data + dstStart, src + srcStart, (srcEnd - srcStart) * sizeof(value_type));
    }
```

So, my question is: could this lead to problems? If so, what are they?

Comment: Some complex data types do not take well to being moved with low-level functions like `memmove`.  Consider a class that contains a pointer to one of its members. That pointer will be pointing to the wrong slot in the array. This is exactly what could happen with a `std::string` with Small String Optimization. Use the move constructor and move assignment operator instead.

Comment: Copy Elision does not mean moving an object's raw bytes from one location to another. That is what move semantics are meant for. Copy Elision avoids constructing a copy of an object when it can be optimized away. For instance, when a function returns an object by value, rather than constructing and turning a temp object, copying the temp into the caller's receiving variable, and then destroying the temp, Copy Elision will simply have the function construct the final object in the caller's variable directly, thus voiding the need for a temp object on return.

Comment: When it all works. Get a code review. https://codereview.stackexchange.com